# Brightness changes watching fullscreen movie with subtitles

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, brightness, subtitles, media-player-classic

I'm having problems while playing movies fullscreen with subtitles on my new notebook.
When a subtitle appears on screens, the screen brightness changes, and then returns normal when the subtitle goes away.
This problem gets reduced if I change subtitle's color to very dark colors, but if I set subtitles border color as blue or red, brightness has a big variation.

That happens either with VLC and Media Player Classic.

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: I forgot to say I'm using Windows 10

Comment: What is the model of the notebook?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is the Windows Advanced Power Options to ensure the adaptive brightness feature is off.

**Right-click the Start button > Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Balanced (or whichever plan you are using) - Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings > Display > Enable adaptive brightness > "Off" > Apply > OK**

The next thing to check would be the Intel Graphics Properties. The main thing to look for is the "Power" options.

**Right-click the desktop (or click the Intel Graphics system tray icon) > Graphics Properties > Power > On Battery > Display Power Saving Technology > Disable > Apply**

Hopefully, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a feature of your notebook or your operating system.

Try to change your display's backlight intensity/brightness using hotkeys (depends on your notebook maker, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> for HP machines, <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> for Asus machines, for example), usually this fixes your backlight to the intensity you select.

You can also search for "disable adaptive brightness" for your operating system.

If you submit your notebook's model and operating system that would be helpful.

---

Now I see your comment, for **Windows 10** here is an answer on SuperUser:
https://superuser.com/a/1008421/308450

Comment: I've already tried to disable Display Power Saving Technology from intel graphic options but that doesn't fix the problem.

Adaptive brightness was disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

The Bitdefender Antivirus had caused this problem by it's Active Profiles feature. These Active profiles changed power mode to High performance and increased screen brightness to the max while playing videos or playing games.

To change the setting, go to:

Tools > Profiles > 'Configure' in Movie Profile > Uncheck "Adjust Power Plans for Movies"

… and save.

Answer (score 0):

If u r using Media Player Classic, there is a solution to this age old problem. In Subtitle => styles settings page put a tick on "Link Alpha Channels" option and voila the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the problem only occurs with bright colors, maybe try disabling HDR if possible or applicable.  Other than that, see if you can disable Adaptive Contrast or Adaptive Brightness.