# Can't disable dynamic contrast on laptop when on battery power

Tags: windows-10, laptop

I have an XPS 15, with an Nvidia GeForce GX 1050 Ti graphics card, and also Intel UHD 630 (I'm not entirely sure how they work, but both appear in the device manager). My OS is Windows 10, and the issue has stayed over multiple updates. It's been happening since I got the computer.

The issue is that when I open different windows, applications, or websites, it changes the contrast, which results in elements on the screen becoming darker and others brighter. Overall, it ends up making everything look really washed out and dim. It doesn't adjust back up to the proper brightness unless I change the brightness again manually.

The issue occurs when either the computer is unplugged from power, or when the computer is plugged in while asleep and then reopened. Plugging in the computer while it is awake fixes the issue.

What I have tried:

Restarted the computer, many times
Adaptive brightness is off.
Looked in the Nvidia control panel for settings, but couldn't find anything there.

I haven't tried [this](https://superuser.com/a/1372409/1038847) solution, for fear of deleting things in System32, as well as the answer having no verification of any sort.

If you look around online, there's tons of different links all talking about the same issue, but none of the solutions that I see have worked for me. For the most part, they just say "disable adaptive brightness," which I tried but doesn't work.

Relevant links:
https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=1396135
https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/949298/dynamic-contrast-option-gone-from-nvidia-control-panel/
[Can't disable dynamic contrast ratio (or auto brightness) on new gaming PC](https://superuser.com/questions/1252307/cant-disable-dynamic-contrast-ratio-or-auto-brightness-on-new-gaming-pc)
https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/718dw8/cant_disable_dynamic_contrast_ratio_or_auto/ [linked from previous thread]
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/screen-keeps-dimming-on-its-own/934da7b2-2318-4fdd-9355-9b3ac9b5fdcc [not entirely sure, but I suspect it's the same issue]
https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=278111.0
https://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?38038-Autobrightness-based-on-lightness-of-items-on-screen
https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Inspiron-14-auto-contrast-brightness-changes/td-p/4120327

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I've found the answer [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-you-completely-disable-adaptive-brightness/b0161873-4ebb-4070-bdad-fdcc01f17e16).

While I'd already tried this on batter power with no results (it was already off), I just tried it with my laptop plugged in (when it was experiencing no issues) and found that it was turned on.. so I turned it off. When I unplugged my computer, the issue was no longer present.

Answer (score 0):

Start the "Intel Graphics Control Panel" app, click on the "Power" icon at bottom, click the "On battery" to the left and click the "Disable" checkbox under the "Display power saving technology"

[image]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/W0mgmbw.png
I'm getting this message when I try to open the intel control panel. Do you know the issue? Google isn't helping me.

Comment: And what happens if you try to download and install latest Intel graphics drivers from Intel website?

Comment: I've found the solution already; it was basically this, but I went through a different app instead and it worked.