# how to disable "intel display power saving technology"

Tags: windows-10, laptop, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

I'm using a Dell Vostro 5490 running Windows 10. Under "display adapters," for me it says

```
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 
NVIDIA GeForce MX250
```

I tried disabling the `Intel Display Power Saving Technology`, because the automatic foreground/background screen brightness adjustment is annoying. But I can't seem to find the option listed on [most guides](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln309126/lcd-brightness-constantly-changing-with-intel-display-power-setting-enabled?lang=en). There is no `Display Power Saving Technology` checkbox. There isn't even an `Enable adaptive brightness` setting in my power options.

[image: In the Intel Graphics Command Center]

[image: No Enable adaptive brightness setting]

Comment: The option isn’t present in the version your using, the tutorial you linked to, is using only applicable to a version from more than 2 years ago.

Comment: So am I stuck with this "feature"?

Comment: I was simply providing an explanation for the reason the option is missing.  Which is the reason it was a comment instead of an answer

Answer (score 14):

**Method 1 : Disable Adaptive brightness in the Registry**

- start `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\Media\Brighten Movie`
- Double-click on `ProcAmpBrightness`, set to `0` and click OK
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\Media\Darken Movie`
- Double-click on `ProcAmpBrightness`, set to `0` and click OK
- Exit `regedit` and reboot

**Method 2 : Disable Intel display power saving technology**

Disabling Intel display power saving technology is complicated by the fact that
the Intel Graphics Control Panel no longer shows the option for disabling it.
Registry work is now required for that:

- Launch regedit
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001`
- Find `FeatureTestControl`, double-click it and copy its value to the clipboard
  (mine is `8280`)
- Open the Calculator, set it to Programmer mode, click HEX, then paste the value
- Click BIN (mine: 1000001010000000)
- Change the 5th bit from the end to 1 (mine: 1000001010010000)
- Click again on HEX and copy to the clipboard (Ctrl-C)
- Set `FeatureTestControl` to this value
- Reboot

A PowerShell package that does all these manipulations can be found in
[Github dpst-control](https://github.com/orev/dpst-control).
After unzipping, you may use its scripts, named appropriately
`get-status.bat`, `disable-dpst.bat` and `enable-dpst.bat`.

**Method 3 : Run Power troubleshooter**

- Run *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot*
- Click *Power > Run the troubleshooter*

Comment: You might want to for purposes of clarity provide the hex value of each of the binary values.  The correct value is apparently 0x8280?

Comment: @Ramhound: The correct value is whatever is derived from the user's computer. I only found one bit described from 32, and that also lightly mentioned on non-official posts. I don't know the other bits.

Comment: `FeatureTestControl` wasn't present in `\0001`, it was in `\0000`, is that okay? And it's Hex value was `8240`

Comment: Yes, the specific sub-key may vary (should have mentioned that). For hex `8240` this gives `8250`.

Comment: that's weird, on my calculator, it's saying invalid input when I plug in the binary number

Comment: The calculator should be in Programmer mode, and you should click on HEX before pasting.

Comment: yeah, and I copied the binary value onto note pad, and it was padding the string with some weird character on either end. I noticed it when I tried to copy it in to a python interpreter to try and convert it that way

Comment: Funny, I also used notepad and I didn't get any parasite characters on the BIN value. I needed to select it all in the calculator, though, before Ctrl-C picked it all up.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but it didn't work, I'm still noticing the automatic brightness adjustment.

Comment: This might mean that the problem is not with Intel display power saving, but with another feature of Windows. Can you edit your post and describe exactly what you are seeing? Is it brightness changing or contrast changing?

Comment: Apparently no Windows problem. I changed my answer - Methods 1 and 3 are new.

Comment: I can confirm that method 2 may also help for cases where the Intel UHD graphics control panel does not save the settings changed by the user.

Comment: Method 2 works for me (i have Intel Graphic Adapter). One addition - FeatureTestControl isn't present in \0001, it is in \0000

Comment: Method 1 was sufficient for me to disable the adaptive contrast that was infuriating me when browsing websites in dark mode in Chrome.

Comment: Wanted to add there is a Github script for this  https://github.com/orev/dpst-control --- also, on a recent LG Gram, the issue turned out to be bloarware that I disabled from startup in Task Manager

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [Method 2 of harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1487212/1149878), you can always disable the Intel Display Power Saving Technology or Adaptive Brightness Settings by turning off the Display Power Savings Options.

[image: turning off Display Power Savings]

However, the problem is Intel does not save this setting changed by the user and the Display Power Savings Options will be automatically enabled everytime you reboot. After you follow **Method 2**, open Intel Graphics Command Center again and the Display Power Savings option should disappear. This works for my Lenovo laptop which has two graphics card.

[image: Display Power Savings option disappears]

Note that you have only 1 graphics card, then your `FeatureTestControl` will be in `\0000` subkey. If you have 2 graphics card like mine, then your `FeatureTestControl` might be in `\0000` or `\0001` subkey. You can check your `DriverDesc` in both subkeys and I assume that the `FeatureTestControl` will only appear in the subkey in which the `DriverDesc` is an Intel Graphics Card.

Comment: Not true that you can "always" disable Display Power Savings in Intel's app. Infuriatingly, all these settings shown in these screenshots under System > Power have randomly disappeared from my Graphics Command Center. I used to have the problem of this DPST somehow turning on, even though it was set to off. I used to toggle it on and off again, and that seemed to work. Now, randomly, all those settings have vanished. The System > Power screen only shows the top frame, with battery info, and everything below is simply blank. 

I used Method 2 in harrymc's answer, and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [GitHub repository (orev/dpst-control)](https://github.com/orev/dpst-control) that allows you to easily enable or disable Display Power Saving Technology by running a script file.

1. Clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/orev/dpst-control.git`
2. Open the repo root directory in File Explorer
3. Right click on `disable-dpst.bat` and click "Run as Administrator" to disable DPST (or `enable-dpst.bat` to enable)
4. Reboot your computer

For your reference, this script file works on my Surface Pro 6 with Windows 10 version 20H2 (October 2020 update).

Comment: This worked perfectly for my Windows Surface Go.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem and after a long search discovered that the function is taken on by the 'EcoPower' function in the Dell BIOS (at least on my Dell XPS 13).

Boot into Dell BIOS Setup, go to Video > Eco Power > Enable EcoPower > OFF

[image]

Comment: It came enabled by default on my dell laptop. Thanks.

Comment: After trying all the other options, THIS worked for me perfectly. But my Bios setup was different. In my case, *Dell BIOS Setup > Video > Dynamic Brightness Control > Disable*

Answer (score 2):

Display Power Saving Technology can be turned off in Intel UHD Control Panel (driver ver. 26.20.100.7810), but to my dismay, it turns itself on relentlessly whenever I reboot. Lenovo ThinkPad 590.
Registry: FeatureTestControl exists only in the \0000 subkey, not in \0001. Just search for it globally. Changing it there seems to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Intel-based graphic in your notebook, you need to use Intel® Graphics Control Panel.

Run the Control panel and click on the Power section at the bottom:
[image: Intel® Graphics Control Panel]

Disable the Display Power Saving Technology section:
[image: Power settings]

Now it's working as expected! (Tested on Thinkpad X1 - graphic: 620)

Answer (score 0):

As per [Intel Support](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P0000490S7MSAU/intel-dpst-active-contrast-issue?language=en_US), they recommend:

1. Click on the Start button, then search for "Power Options".
2. Click on "Change plan settings".
3. Now click on "Change advanced power settings" to launch the Power Options Advanced Settings.
4. Scroll down until you get to the "Display" section and click on the plus sign to show the sub-menus. Now click on the plus sign next to "Enable adaptive brightness" to expose its settings.
5. Change the settings to off.

Reboot and test for the desired change. If the problem persists:

6. Get into the Intel(R) HD Graphics Control Panel (CUI)
7. Go to the "Power" section
8. On the left navigation panel, select the "On Battery" option
9. More options appear on the main panel; pick "Display Power Saving Technology" | "Disable" | Apply | Reboot and retest.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 What you illustrated was not an exact match, so I wanted to make sure. Understand you're frustrated, but now we know exactly what to rule out.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching (I also tried checking Intel graphics command center settings as well as system power settings, but both without right results, I stumbled upon this solution):

Right click on Desktop and then click on

> Intel Graphic Settings -> Power -> On Battery -> Display Power Saving Technology -> Disable

Answer (score 0):

i was facing this problem with a DELL Latitude E5570 with windows 11 and intel HD Graphics 530, the new intel graphics command center does not have the disable powe saving technology option, neither the bios has this option, so, searching I found that I have an app installed called Dell Command Power Manager. In this app there is an option called "Battery extensor" (or something like that because the app is in another language), I activated the battery extensor option and changed the screen brightness to 75% and screen reduced flickering, it only happens when I turn on or off the laptop.