# Dell XPS brightness changes automatically even when Intel Power Saving is disabled

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, intel-graphics, dell-xps, powersave

How to disable "Intel Display Power Saving Technology"?

I'm using a Dell XPS 13 9380 running windows 10 (cry).

When a bright image is displayed, the screen brightens. When dark images are on the screen, it dims.
The result is constantly changing brightness. It changes whether on battery or plugged in.

I have adjusted all of my power settings to high performance.
I have looked in Intel's HD Graphics Control Panel, there is no option to disable it.

Following these protocols (https://superuser.com/a/1487212/1164457), I have:

- disabled adaptive brightness in the registry
- disabled Intel display power-saving technology in the registry

After rebooting and confirming the settings changed, the screen still changes brightness constantly.

This "feature" makes it hard to see everything.

Answer (score 3):

Had same issue, after hours of searching I found that it is a setting in the BIOS.

Here is how to fix:

1. Boot into BIOS mode
2. Go to 'display' tab (on some models it is under 'video')
3. Scroll down to 'EcoPower'
4. Turn it off
5. Save changes
6. Good to go!

Thanks to https://superuser.com/a/1556441/1202970

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to help the people out there. Imagine trying all of the answers that doesn't help, just to find out that it's a simple hidden setting...

Comment: David, there is a discoverability problem here.  The linked question is about Intel's power-saving options, and that's what the OP *thought* they were asking about as well.  It turns out *not* to be an Intel driver setting, but a Dell vendor-specific additional setting.  I think there's value in leaving this question open for Dell owners who can't figure out why, even after twiddling Intel driver settings, their system keeps using dynamic brightness. (I just suggested a title change to reflect this.)