# Cannot fully disable Intel DPST (Display Power Saving Technology) Lenovo X1 Yoga (2nd Gen) OLED

Tags: windows-10, display, lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics

This has been driving me crazy since I bought this laptop. I cannot fully disable Intel DPST no matter what I try.

This is a software issue. I run linux as a dual boot and this issue does not exist in any distro I have tried.

I am running the latest driver found [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/LAPTOPS-AND-NETBOOKS/THINKPAD-X-SERIES-LAPTOPS/THINKPAD-X1-YOGA-TYPE-20JD-20JE-20JF-20JG/downloads/DS120313)

The closest I have gotten is [here](https://mikebattistablog.wordpress.com/2016/05/27/disable-intel-dpst-on-sp4/)

Which appears to work UNTIL I change the brightness of the screen. As soon as I change the brightness the screen jarringly changes contrast/brightness and begins to reproduce the issue again until I reboot. (will update with a video when I get home)

Due to this being an OLED panel, whatever method is used to change the brightness differs from that of other displays (I learned this when I installed linux and had to write my own script to change the brightness). My best theory is that this feature is broken in the driver specifically for OLED panels that somehow resets the DPST bit. Since the windows intel driver is a black box I cannot validate this theory.

Before you suggest a solution please look at these links. Similar questions have been asked about this before - but this question is specifically for this model/configuration of this laptop. 
Here is a list of things that I have tried and do not work:

- [Brightness changes while "Adaptive Brightness" is disabled in Windows 8.1/10](https://superuser.com/questions/994443/brightness-changes-while-adaptive-brightness-is-disabled-in-windows-8-1-10/994448#994448)
- https://superuser.com/a/569461
- https://lifehacker.com/disable-windows-annoying-adaptive-brightness-feature-on-1567886994
- [Everything in this thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X1-Yoga-OLED-2ndGen-sporadic-color-settings-changes/td-p/3723275)

Any Technical insight would be greatly appreciated. Is it possible to contact Intel/file a bug on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a sneaky Lenovo utility running in the background called `ChromaTune`. You can uninstall it at the path below in the screenshot. You will lose the Lenovo color profile settings, but your screen will no longer change color randomly based on what is on the screen. 
[image]